# What is Soft DFU mode, and how do I exit it

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I was trying to restore my jalbroken Iphone 4 today, and after a couple fail attempts I got it to what redsn0w is calling 'soft dfu mode'. Any idea how to exit this mode? I tried holding down the home and power button for 2 mins but no luck.

Comment: Never heard of soft DFU. Do you have a link to it's definition or how you came to hear it? I am aware of only recovery mode and DFU mode on iOS hardware and software at present. Perhaps this is something new, but my guess is someone didn't want to say normal recovery mode and instead made up Soft DFU. (Unless they mean to use software to initiate a DFU mode).

Comment: @cubearth Does this article help, although reiterates bmikes comment above http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/36887/what-is-ios-dfu-mode/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck in soft dfu mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132806/stuck-in-soft-dfu-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exit soft DFU:

1. Hold down the Home and Power button for 10 seconds.
2. Release.
3. Push Power button.
4. Your iPhone should boot up and work fine. *(At least, it worked for my iPod touch 4G.)*

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold down the Sleep button and Home button at the same time.
2. After a few seconds the Apple logo appears and the iPhone will boot.
3. Your iPhone is now out of DFU mode.